# Difference between `template` and `layout` properties of Ember Component?

Tags: ember.js, ember-components

The [API doc](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#property_templateName) says:

> Specifying a component's **templateName** is deprecated without also
>   providing the **layout** or **layoutName** properties.

So what's the difference between **template** and **layout** for a component? And in what situation will we need to specify both **template** and **layout**?

It looks like that **template** is the **{{yield}}** part of a layout?

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided doesn't contain the marked text - it might've changed, so not sure what the context is. But essentially, layout will be used as the 'yeild' part of another template. (A template can use multiple layout pages)